# Building cmake generated UWP windows desktop project results in error MC6000 (missing WindowsBase, ...)

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, cmake

I created a simple Windows UWP solution with windows visual studio 2019.
I did not make any changes to it but closed visual studio.

Then I wrote a simple cmake file for it.
However, it fails in "cmake --build" like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets(268,9): 
error MC6000: Project file must include the .NET Framework assembly 
'WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework' in the reference list. 
[App1\out\App1.csproj]
```

When I add the requested .NET files with VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES property, there is a different error:

```
App1\MainPage.xaml(9,5): error MC3074: The tag 'ThemeResource' does not exist 
in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'. 
Line 9 Position 5. [App1\out\App1.csproj]
```

I also tried adding all and combinations of these calls to CMakeLists.txt but they did not have any effect:

```
set_property (SOURCE "App.xaml" PROPERTY VS_XAML_TYPE "ApplicationDefinition")
target_compile_options (App1 PRIVATE "/langversion:default")
set_property (TARGET App1 PROPERTY DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.7.2")
set_property (TARGET App1 PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)
```

I cannot overcome these problems. 
I generate and compile the solution like this:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=WindowsStore -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0 -S . -B out
cmake --build out
```

Cmake version is 3.14.19050301-MSVC_2.

The source files are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ekGxtEXC2mqMpJJb_kKMT-5HmM6QjuFx), including the original by visual studio created solution files and my written CMakeLIsts.txt file.

Expected result would be a cmake compiling solution which looks as much as possible like the native solution.

Probably there is just a simple error but I cannot find it.

Comment: `.NET Framework assembly 'WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework'` this assembly is for WPF, not for UWP. Seems like, something is wrong in `cmake` config or targets. Is it built in VS2019?

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio 16 2019. I tried to keep the CMakeFiles.txt simple but apparently something is missing.

Comment: According to cmake, those "DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=WindowsStore -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0" parameters should do the trick.